# How can I get the recoll package to index markdown (.md) files?

Tags: markdown, indexing, recoll

From what I understand markdown is pretty similar to text and html, which are all indexed by the [recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) search engine.

However my markdown files with extension .md are not being indexed. I have checked the filters and I am not sure which one applies to markdown, or if its support is missing altogether.

If there is a simple way of manually creating a filter then it would be wonderful if someone could help me with creating one. Or if it is a simple setting I'm missing could you please point it out?

I am running the latest version of recoll (1.21.5) on Debian Testing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit `~/.recoll/mimemap`, add the following line:

```
.md = text/plain
```

This will tell recoll to index markdown as normal text, which it is, mostly, so I think that things should "just work"

Comment: Thanks! I added
 .md = text/html
.mmd = text/html
to the ~/.recoll/mimemap file and it works now. The config file examples located at /usr/share/recoll/examples are also very useful